# Mixing a line with pies or sectors

Tags: charts, lightningchart

A table consists of 4 fields:

1. X: time values in ascending order
2. Y: numeric value - double
3. A: numeric value - int
4. B: numeric value - int

I need to create a line chart using the X,Y values. And at each of the x,y points also show a pie/circle  representing the A,B values as follows:

The centre of the pie is the x,y point.
The diameter of the pie is calculated from the values A and B.
The pie will have 2 different coloured slices, the size of each slice is proportion to the value of A and B.

After searching the documentations of lcjs, can this be done using Lightning Charts JS? if not, how about lc.NET?

Any hints is much appriciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In LightningChart JS, I don't believe there is such functionality available.

Something like this should be possible (bar instead of pie)

[image]